Output your shortcode from the plugin in additional fields - joomla 5
I want to output my shortcode from the plugin in additional fields. Unsuccessfully. Maybe there is someone who has encountered this and can tell you?
Here is my plugin code:
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class PlgContentShortcode extends JPlugin
{
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart)
    {
        $replacement1 = $this->replaceMyFunction1();
        $replacement2 = $this->replaceMyFunction2();
        
    
        $article->text = str_replace("[test]", $replacement1, $article->text);

        $article->jcFields = str_replace("[test2]", $replacement2, $article->jcFields);

        
        return true;
    }
    
    private function replaceMyFunction1()
    {
        $result = 'Test 1';
        return $result;
    }
    
    private function replaceMyFunction2()
    {
        $result = 'Test 2';
        return $result;
    }
}


$article->jcfields is an array of fields. You need to loop over them and then make your change on the value of the object.
